# Keeping the camera from going through walls in a first person game in Unity? 

Tags: c#, unity, camera

I'm using a modified version of the standard Unity First Person Controller. At the moment when I stand near walls, the camera clips through and lets me see through the wall. I know about camera occlusion and have implemented it in 3rd person games, but I have no clue how I'd accomplish this in a first person game, since the camera doesn't move from the player at all.

How do other people accomplish this?

Comment: Maybe you could put a sphere collider on a parent game object of the camera?

Comment: Let me try that out

Comment: I haven't messed with the FP controller much in Unity but if your camera is passing through walls, doesn't that mean the _player_ is passing through (or partly into) walls?  Maybe the collidable component(s) of your controller need to be wider.

Comment: Actually, I already have a capsule on the camera, it's what is attached to the camera as a default. However it's not a parent, does the parent part matter? I'll try adding a sphere collider to it, on top of the character controller collider.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's probably an issue of your near clipping plane of your camera being further away than the radius on your character controller.

Either make the collision radius bigger or make the near clipping plane smaller.

If you look in the editor at the camera frustum you can easily tell if it's too far out compared to your collision radius.  Here's an example:

[image]

Notice how the rear plane is clipping through the wall.

Comment: How can I go about making the near clipping plane smaller?

Comment: @TimothyWilliams it's a parameter in the inspector for the camera component.

Answer (score 0):

+1 to Rubber Mallet.

In "Unity 3.x Game Development Essentials" I saw the same example. Just put the camera on the top of sphere object(with collider). Also you could try to disable mesh renderer on it if you do not want to see the sphere.

Comment: I actually already have it that way, I use a charactercontroller, so it's not that that's causing the issues. I think it's what Tetrad said.

Comment: Actually, I was thinking of the 3rd Person Controller. I'm pretty sure Tetrad's got the right idea.